# SQL: count of replica entries in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, unique

Simplistically I have a table that looks like this:

```
ColA | ColB |
-----+------+
EE34 | Woo  |
ER56 | fro  |
EE34 | eco  |
QW34 | Sddg |
EE34 | zoo  |
ER56 | safe |
```

I need a select statement for SQL Server that produces:

```
ColA | Count |
-----+-------+
EE34 | 3     |
ER56 | 2     |
QW34 | 1     |
```

This could be running over a table with 100k+ records.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  ColA, COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        ColA
```

Or I am missing something?

Comment: Nope, you're not missing anything..
Altghough you could use something like this:
SELECT Cola, COUNT(ColA) as Count FROM mytable GROUP BY ColA

Now you know for sure that cola gets counted and not just al rows.

Comment: `@Bloeper`: the results will only differ for the `NULL` values of `ColA` (the count will return `0` instead of actual number of `NULL` values)